# How to extract all ifconfig data in awk except loopback

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, awk

I am writing a script which includes a function to list all interfaces EXCEPT loopback from ifconfig. The logic I'm using is to look for the loopback block by a regular expression and negating it. The command i use is `ifconfig|awk '!/lo:/,/\n\n+/'`
but this is still returning all the interfaces. When i remove the `!`, only the loopback address is returned. Then why is the earlier command returning everything instead of everything except loopback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
ifconfig | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\n\n"} !/^lo/{print}'
```